# nth-child selectors (pseudo classes) in IE 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I need the expression

```
`tr:nth-child(2n){background-color: #ddd;}`
```

to color each second row for a table which I create dynamically. But this expression works only for IE9.  So is it possible to enable these CSS3 pseudo classes for IE8, too?

Answer (score 3):

For IE8 not as far as I know it. However there is a solution with jQuery using `.filter(":even").` [see this documentation](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) about it. It will work with IE7 or newer.

Comment: But JQuery didn't work, because I also have rows in table which shouldn't be colored! And unfortunately JQuery ignores css statements which are set by .class{background-color:#fffff;}!

Answer (score 0):

You can get nth child selectors in IE with a JavaScript shim such as [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/). This article is also interesting for faking the functionality http://abouthalf.com/2011/07/06/poor-mans-nth-child-selector-for-ie-7-and-8/.

Comment: But for table which is creating dynamcially did this not work :( Especially for a number of rows, not only for one row!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by Prototype JS. Works also in IE8.

```
var rowCounter = 0;
$$('tr').each(function (row) { /*$$('tr') == array of tr tags*/
    if (rowCounter % 2 === 0) { /*modulo dividing find even element*/
        row.addClassName('even');
    }
    rowCounter += 1;
});
```

Visit: http://jsfiddle.net/P9SHy/3/